# TDD a card game - where to start?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

One of the most important rule in TDD is to write the simplest test to implement the simplest code in order to get closer to the end of a project.

I'd like to implement the game of [Briscola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Briscola). 
It's a simple card game, with 40 cards, 2-5 players, and simple rules.

To start, I thought the best thing to implement was the core of the game, playing a hand.

To play a hand I need at least 2 players in a game, both will have 3 cards in hand, both have to be able to play one card each, and the game has to be able to decide the winner, and count points.

That looks like a lot of things to implement before passing that first test.

Should I still write that test down, and use it to implement everything needed ? 
Or should I write tests for everything before trying to make that test pass ?

One thing that makes me reluctant to write a test as simple as "an_ace_is_worth_11_points" is that I'm afraid the design I'd start implementing would absolutely not fit the design to make a more concrete and complete test pass.

Comment: [Where to Start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start)

Comment: I'm a big fan of you @RobertHarvey , I tried to be as specific as I could and I tried to find as much content trying to find an answer to my question. After several days not finding anything (yes I know how to TDD a bowling game), I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: "True" TDD suggests that you start by writing the smallest possible test for the smallest possible thing that you can get to pass.  Neither of your proposed options fits that bill.  I suggest instead that you come up with a sensible basic design for your game, and then begin writing tests and implementations for those tests.

Comment: Notice that even the bowling game kata has a bunch of unspoken design decisions made before the first test is written.

Comment: Think about the objects that you will be creating and the order you will need them in.  For example maybe card class and tests(suits, numbers)  deck class and tests ( number of cards, shuffle) player class and tests, hand class and tests, game class and tests(start game, deal, track points, determine winner)

Comment: But, isn't TDD supposed to help you in designing your code ? That's why I didn't do any design first, I thought TDD would drive me to write testable / efficient code. I thought making a design first would hinder this aspect of TDD.

Comment: TDD may sometimes help in designing interfaces of modules (or classes), but it won't help you in designing the overall structure of an application. You need to make some decisions about your modules and their responsibilities and dependencies before you can write any meaningful unit tests.

Comment: @COMEFROM I completely disagree with that. To understand responsibilities and dependencies is **EXACTLY the very first benefit of TDD**. The first "wow" when starting this discipline.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard: TDD will help you for the part of the design which is called "testability".

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti It's impossible to write a meaningful test without having any thought of a testable unit and its functionality. In terms of object oriented programming, you need to name an object (or a class) and a method to write a meaningful test. TDD won't tell you what the first object and the first method should be. That decision is not at all trivial and it's very easy get horribly wrong.

Comment: That's why you do not start with code but with an abstract domain model, you create a _language_ for your team. It doesn't need to be super specific (especially if you keep agile). Then you start sketching architecture. THEN you try to put things in code, starting with an abstract view (well supported by tests). Here you can even review your architecture before writing any meaningful code in your model. If you directly jump to code then IMHO you skip an important real word validation of your idea. Results? Worse code or more time to rewrite it later.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Sounds like you're agreeing with us: TDD does not create an architecture/design for you.  You have to do that yourself.

Comment: Yes, I do. I just don't agree with the part about "dependencies and responsibilities". I think "TDD" will **help** you (not replace) to define dependencies between modules and their responsibilities. (note I'm using TDD but what I really mean is "writing high level _tests_ before actual model code")

Answer (score 8):

Because you're *running too fast*. When reading *specifications* you should stop as soon as you can write some code (after you understood the domain). I usually read the domain model specifications few times until I think I understood them and then I read them again using an highlighter to mark important bits to start coding.

> To start, I thought the best thing to implement was the core of the game, playing a hand.
>   To play a hand I need at least 2 players in a game, both will have 3 cards in hand, both have to be able to play one card each, and the game has to be able to decide the winner, and count points.

First of all write down the complete specifications for this game. Everything, even if you think you have it clear in your mind. It doesn't even need to be strictly formal.

Let's go through this word by word, the first keyword to highlight is **game**. You will, probably, then need a `Game` class you want to create. Let's write a test method (syntax is for C# but the important part is the concept):

```
[TestMethod]
void CanCreateNewGame()
{
    var game = new Game();
}
```

So far so good, we just want to be sure we can create a `Game` object and it doesn't throw any exception. If we will introduce a factory (for example to join an on-line pending game) then this is the test we need to rewrite. Let's write code to make it pass:

```
public sealed class Game { }
```

Now continue scanning your specifications, you have **players**. You will then need to create them, same as above. You see then **...in a game...**. It means they must be stored in the `Game` class and they can be from 2 to 5, you need also a collection.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanCreatePlayer()
{
    var game = new Game();
    game.Players.Add(new Player());
}
```

Let's declare the class and its collection `PlayerCollection` then add it to the game class:

```
public sealed class Player { }
public sealed class PlayerCollection : Collection<Player> { }

public sealed class Game
{
    public PlayerCollection Players { get; } = new PlayerCollection();
}
```

Our tests are green, we can now move to the next important part (the number of players). When we need at least two players and no more than 5? When we **start** a game:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
public void CannotStartGameWithLessThan2Players()
{
    var game = new Game();
    game.Start();
}
```

Make it compile, add `Start()` to `Game`:

```
public void Start()
{
    if (Players.Count < MinimumNumberOfPlayers || Players.Count > MaximumNumberOfPlayers)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("...");
}
```

Just continue like this until your application is completed. Now you can move that check into a separate function `EnsureThereIsRightNumberOfPlayers()` and you already have all the tests to do it safely. I'd suggest to also add assertions to help you with tests (countless times an assertion failed when running my tests and I found I had to add more tests...) but it's probably outside the scope of your question.

Writing tests before code will also help to have a better code coverage and to keep your code testable even when you just started using unit testing.

---

What I shown above is a *literal* TDD approach, I am often little bit more pragmatic and I write bigger code blocks and/or multiple tests in one shot. For example I will NEVER write `int Sum(int a, int b) => 2;` because I need to pass the test `Assert.AreEqual(2, Sum(1, 1,))` (to fix it in the next test when I need to verify `Sum(-1, -1)`). I'd write, whenever possible, enough code to pass the test but using what may be a *true* implementation (which I may refine and refactor later because I already have tests in-place).

With some experience with TDD you will find what's the best compromise for you.

---

## TDD as a tool to study the domain

**Note**: [TDD won't replace design phase](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/231418/49723), it's not its role. It will, however, help you to refine your design from an abstract domain point of view to a *practical* implementation. Also note that the *type* of tests you write in this case is pretty different from the type of tests you write on a *normal* TDD approach.

Sometimes the *domain* isn't perfectly clear and you need to write some code to outline overall architecture. This case, IMO, is when you have **greater benefits with TDD**. Didn't ever happen to write a *great* model which is a pain to consume? If you start *consuming* your model first then this won't ever happen.

In this case I find convenient to write a slightly complex test method to understand who the *actors* are, for example a very naive first approach to the problem may be:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanSetupGame()
{
    // I have a game
    var game = new Game();

    // With at least two named players
    game.Players.Add(new Player("Adam"));
    game.Players.Add(new Player("Jon"));

    // I can start the game
    game.Start();

    // And I keep playing until there are cards in the table...
    while (game.Cards.Count > 0)
    {
        // Print current cards to...console?
        var availableCards = game.CurrentPlayer.Cards;

        // Read user input from?
        var selectedCard = availableCards.First();

        game.CurrentPlayer.Play(selectedCard);
    }
}
```

As you can see you immediately see what your objects have to do, you need to keep track of the current player, its cards and stop playing when...cards are finished. You also immediately see that more users may share the same screen and so on...

Of course you will need to write a lot of code before this test can pass (you may temporarily `[Ignore]` it) and it MUST change/evolve over time but it will be your *GPS* to write all the other smaller tests you need. You may even find that some of these "high level abstraction" tests should be moved to integration tests, for example. Even better. Note that you should not throw away these tests, they're great self-documenting examples and the **first thing that someone else should see when studying your code**.

Writing this kind of rough code will greatly help you to better understand the Big Picture before writing one single line in your model (and some IDEs let you generate stubs from this code...). After you wrote above code you may then think *"Shouldn't everything be inside `Start()`?"*. You will then drop that `while` and you will next think *"How should I get inputs?"* and add, for example, an `Input` property of type `Stream` to the `Game` class. You will do the same for `Output` and you will then ask yourself *"What if I want to make it graphical?"* and replace it with with a `UserInteraction` class. Keep changing, refining and increasing your understanding. You won't write a model (and its tests) you need to throw away because it's a pain to use (which may also cause the calling code to be a mess because you don't want to throw away such *beautiful* already written model...)

Note that this *consumer to implementation* approach will also help you to refine some of your architectural decisions, for example:

- Is the language a *good fit* to express the model? Should I move to another language? To a DSL?
- Do I need any framework? Are frameworks I supposed to use good for this job? Did they drive in the choice of the language?
- Are performance good enough? Should I review my algorithms?
- This package/module/class depend on the other one to perform its task. Is it a *good enough* decision or should I move responsibilities?
- Did I practically put too many responsibilities on this class and I'd better move them out? Is there a chance to reuse this code somewhere else?

You probably have already noted that DDD, TDD and - when dealing with UI - lean UX design aren't separate steps or different approaches (!!!) but they go pretty well all together.

Comment: What do you think about other comments stating I should first create a design to then know in which direction the code will be going ?

Comment: @SteveChamaillard: there are lots of higher level design decisions you typically make beforehand, like which programming language & tools & framework to pick, are you going to design for web or desktop or  a mobile platform, will you have a separate model layer etc. TDD helps you for the lower level design decisions, especially testability.

Comment: @DocBrown agree, when you have some code to write then you already took some very important architectural decisions but, I think, TDD will then help you to refine those decisions (can I _write_ a _good_ representation of the domain using this language? should I use this or that framework? With this rough performance test - performed inside my unit testing - can I assert that response time of a typical web application is _good enough_?)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: the OP was asking about Robert Harvey's suggestion to come up with a basic design first. Robert's comment should be seen in context with answers like [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231416/building-complex-algorithms-with-tdd/231418#231418) (which I fully agree to).

Comment: @Doc understand! Yes, I agree about that. You must have an idea of _what you're doing/where you're going_ before even starting to write the very first line of code. What I mean is that TDD will [help you to **refine**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/357268/tdd-a-card-game-where-to-start/357290?noredirect=1#comment773211_357268) your design

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks to your answer, I did an "outside" test which was a bit less complete than your example, stopping at the ```game.start()``` call, and asserting things after this. I then wrote a test for each line, to finally make the whole test pass ! Now I felt like I really went further to the end of the project :)

Comment: @Steve exactly, I think you done right. My last test already went to far to inspect my first hypothetical design (highlighting its flaws, BTW), that's why I said TDD is (also) a _tool_ to _study_ the domain.

Comment: A very good answer. I think it's very important to understand that there are a lot of design decisions shown in the test example here: having "Game" and "Player" as classes, allowing creating a game with no players, allowing player objects mutate the state of a game (possibly leading to a problematic circular dependency that has to be changed later on) etc. An experienced programmer like you is conscious about these decisions when writing tests even without sketching out a design beforehand. A novice programmer who's just learning TDD might fail to notice them.

Comment: @COMEFROM I didn't think about it in this way. Yes, there are many implicit/explicit design decisions (and some more still not explored) here. It's what I like TDD for: try/test the design in practice. I thought it's something useful especially when beginning with TDD because you immediately see its benefits but I may well be wrong about it!

Answer (score 4):

Each of the things you mentioned is a testable unit to me.  Doing a whole hand would be perhaps dozens of tests.

I would probably start up with the basic setup pieces.  Test to make sure that a Deck object can be created (or fetched from a Factory or whatever).  Test to make sure it can deal cards.  How do you represent Players?  are they objects or something else?  Is there a "Table" object or "Game" object that encapsulates state in some fashion?  These are all questions you'll have to design your way out of.  But starting with whatever you know (e.g. that there will be a deck of cards, that deck will have 52 cards of 4 suits, and so on) is where you begin.

Answer (score 3):

> That looks like a lot of things to implement before passing that first test.

Stop, you have your activities in the wrong order.  Before you go off and implement a bunch of things to *calculate* the correct answer, you first need a passing test.

That usually means a check, and a trivial implementation that returns a hardcoded answer that satisfies the check.

Roman numeral kata:

```
Assert.that(sut.toRoman(50)).equals("L");

String toRoman(int value) {
    return 50;
}
```

Bowling game kata:

```
Assert.that(sut.score()).equals(0);

int score() {
    return 0;
}
```

Mars Rover kata

```
String input = "5 5\n1 2 N\nLMLMLMLMM\n3 3 E\nMMRMMRMRRM\n";
String expectedOutput = "1 3 N\n5 1 E\n";

Assert.that(sut.run("5 5\n1 2 N\nLMLMLMLMM\n3 3 E\nMMRMMRMRRM\n")).equals("1 3 N\n5 1 E\n");

String run(String input) {
    return "1 3 N\n5 1 E\n";
}
```

> Where to start?

So for a given unit, you should always be starting from a passing test (probably a trivially passing one, like above), before you begin fleshing out the "real" implementation.

[Two different approaches](https://8thlight.com/blog/georgina-mcfadyen/2016/06/27/inside-out-tdd-vs-outside-in.html) - the outside in approach starts with something big, and encourages you to discover the small parts as you go.  By it nature, it's consumer focused -- "how does the caller invoke this" comes before "how is this implemented".  The inside out approach instead begins with a mental decomposition into components of a solution (players, cars, counting points), picks one, and takes an outside in approach to each component in turn.

I'm not a fan of inside out, myself; the inside out demonstrations I've seen tend to need to deal with a lot of baggage before finally resulting in something useful.

Outside in, I have found, tends to produce [better module decomposition](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc838p/Design/criteria.pdf); you are constantly discovering boundaries to hide the decision to hard code an answer.  The decomposition that we do with the inside out approach is effectively guessing up front where the significant boundaries lie.

Also: naming things *sucks*.  I'd rather get stumped up front guessing a good name for a single entry point than get stumped trying to guess good names for units within the model that I haven't started using yet.

So my recommendation is: Start with a question

- that you know the answer to
- where you can make a reasonable guess at a simple api for the question
- that provides value in isolation